# How to Add a Static Library to a VS 2015 Fortran Project?

Tags: visual-studio, fortran, static-libraries

How do I add a Static Library to a VS 2015 Fortran Project?

I've searched for the answer to this question online, but the solutions I've found (linked below) don't seem to work for me.

[How to link a .LIB in a MS Visual Studio / Intel Fortran project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31975440/how-to-link-a-lib-in-a-ms-visual-studio-intel-fortran-project)
https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows/topic/393843

I'm using VS 2015 and Intel Fortran 2017.

I have created a static library from my Utilities project and I would like to be able to use the 'Utilities.lib' file in a different project (PhysicsCore) without having all of the source included.

I've tried dragging and dropping the 'Utilities.lib' file into the PhysicsCore Project. I've tried adding existing file and adding 'Utilities.lib'. I've tried adding the lib file and all of the '.mod' and '.obj' files. I've tried going under properties -> librarian -> additional dependencies. All of these end with the PhysicsCore project failing to compile due to missing procedures and modules.

I have gotten it to work one way that isn't very helpful. I have added a new project to the solution and then added in all of the '.obj' and '.mod' files and the '.lib' file. Changed the solution settings to not rebuild that project. And then finally added that non-building project as a dependency of the PhysicsCore project.

I feel like I must just be missing something small.

EDIT: years later. I finally came across the issue. If the library were all in `.f90` files everything would work fine, but I'm using modules which require the `.mod` files. Everything was doing what it was supposed to as far as I can tell; however, it didn't behave the way I expected it to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways:

1. Drag the .lib into the project as a source file. You say this didn't work, but it always has when I have done it.
2. In the Linker project properties, add the full path to the .lib to Linker > Input > Additional Dependencies, or just add the .lib name there and add the directory path to Linker > General > Additional Library Directories.
3. If the parent project is also Fortran, right click on the parent project, select Build Dependencies > Project Dependencies. Check the box for the library project. (This does not work if the parent project is not Fortran.)

I would generally recommend #3, as this will also make the .mod files from the library project visible to the parent project. If you choose one of the other methods, you then also have to make any include or .mod files visible by adding the directory path to the project property Fortran > General > Additional Include Directories.

If you need more help with this, I suggest asking in https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-visual-fortran-compiler-for-windows

Comment: #1 and #2 do not work, as I said in my original post. Maybe there is some setting I need to turn on or change, but for the life of me I can't fine it. For #3 some of the names are slightly different than what you said to get to those settings, but a check box doesn't show up unless I actually create a whole additional project to house the static lib in.

Comment: #1 does work if I copy and paste all of the .obj and .mod files from the Utilities project into the debug folder of the Physics project. But that doesn't seem like the expected behavior.

Comment: Further update. #1 also works if I add the directory containing all of the .mod and .obj files to the Project->Properties->Fortran->General->Additional Include Directories.

Comment: Indeed the option for #3 doesn't work unless there is more than one project in the solution. There is no option to enable any of these things - what I'd ask you to do is post in the Intel forum and attach a ZIP containing your .sln and .vfproj files where you have tried option 3 (or 1) without copying in all the .obj and .mod files, plus the buildlog.htm of the executable project after a failed build.

Comment: You only need the .mod files in the include directory.  The .obj files are already in the .lib.

Comment: If one adds the library project as a dependent, then its .mod files are automatically picked up. But if you're not going to do that, then you need to make both the modules and .lib available. I am going to edit my response to clarify that.